# Where to put navigation-related code in angular app?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-route-guards

Currently I have in my AuthGuard constructor a subsription to redux state change below. It will just redirect to original page requested after login. This is not correct place but i don't know where it should be:

auth.guard.ts:

```
this.subscription = this.ngRedux.select<ILoginState>('login')
  .subscribe(newState => {
    if (newState.isLoggedIn) {
        let redirectUrl : string = ngRedux.getState().window.windowData.redirectUrl;
        if (!redirectUrl) {
          redirectUrl = '/map/' + this.tabService.sessionId;
        }
        this.router.navigate([redirectUrl]);
      }
  });
```

I have also other navigation related stuff like below. This is currently in a service that is supposed to manage different browser windows and state syncing across them:

```
/* track url changes and change redux state */
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {   
    this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.windowActions.setOutletActiveRoute(event.urlAfterRedirects));
  }
});
```

Both could be in new navigation-service.ts in core or in app.component.ts. I read [an article about not subscribing in angular service](https://blog.angularindepth.com/when-to-subscribe-a83332ae053) so maybe not service. Also putting everything in app.component sounds bad idea. I would like to put all navigation related stuff to it's own place to separate concerns. What would be recommended way?

Comment: You should not subscribe in authgaurd. Use get state instead because it will run on every route change. you don’t wanna leak memory by keeping many subscriptions open.

Comment: Yes. As I wrote in question the code is not supposed to be in authguard. The question is where. And the purpose of 1st piece of code is to react to login change. i can't use getState. i need to react to login state change that's why there is subsription. It can come after 1 hour. It would never redirect if i use only getState. And the latter code is supposed to run on every route change to sync the redux state for every route change.

Answer (score 0):

Create a app.navigator.ts file and put your navigation logic there, this is not a service or component just a ts file.

app.navigator.ts

```
......


/* track url changes and change redux state */
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {   
    this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.windowActions.setOutletActiveRoute(event.urlAfterRedirects));
  }
});

......
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer @Srinivasan! So is it an angular class? What benefits this approch have (apart from separation of concerns)? Would it be like app-navigation.ts or something?

Comment: yeah you can name it app-navigation.ts as well. Main thing is maintainability and readability. Hope you have gone through https://angular.io/guide/styleguide

Comment: Angular class?  May not be , depends upon your need. We have a ts file named app.config.ts to hold config info no classes at all.

Comment: if no class there is no this -operator for the subscription?

Comment: I did not mean that. Since you have to subscribe and all you definitely need a class , I was trying to say it use classes defending upon your need. @charm Thanks